# Laravel - searching by multiple tags and a string

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-scout

In my Laravel app I have a search function, in said search function the user can search by a query string and a selection of tags.

An ordinary search query would produce a request like the following:

`https://events-portal.test/api/events/search?q=search` where q is the query string.

I also have a series of tags that users can select many of, then the request looks like the following:

`https://events-portal.test/api/events/search?q=search&tags[]=%7B%22slug%22:%22business-development%22%7D`

However, this feels broken as when I paginate Laravel only brings the query string to the next page.

Should I really be passing the entire object to the query string?

Essentially, is there a better way to pass multiple of the same parameter to the query string instead of an object as an array?

**Code**

```
    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $search_term = $request->get('q');
        $tags = $request->get('tags');

        // Organise tags from request into usable array
        $tags = collect($tags)->map(function ($item, $key) {
            return [
                json_decode($item)->slug,
            ];
        })->flatten()->toArray();

        // Build error message if no results are found
        $error = ['error' => "No results found for '{$request->get('q')}'"];

        $error['error'] = count($tags) > 0
            ? $error['error'] . ' with ' . count($tags) . ' tag(s) selected.'
            : $error['error'];

        // If there is a search term, search for events meeting search criteria
        if (!empty($search_term)) {
            $events = Event::search($search_term)->query(function ($query) use ($tags) {
                return $query->listed()
                    ->when(count($tags) > 0, function ($query) use ($tags) {
                        return $query->withTag($tags);
                    })
                    ->select('id', 'title', 'header_image_url', 'location', 'start_datetime', 'finish_datetime');
            })->paginate(6);
        }
        // If there is NO search term, load all listed events meeting tag criteria
        else {
            $events = Event::listed()
                ->withTag($tags)
                ->select('id', 'title', 'header_image_url', 'location', 'start_datetime', 'finish_datetime')
                ->orderBy('start_datetime')
                ->paginate(6);
        }

        return $events->count() ? $events : $error;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If you want your page to be refreshable and still show the same data, you'll want that whole query in the URL (or have some sort of session data which isnt great). Also your controller is a bit odd since you are returning error messages under the `200` status. You might also want to use `$query->when()` as shown here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#conditional-clauses

Comment: I'm a little lost as to why Laravel keeps the query string, but loses the tags array on the next page load.